# select from variable

Tags: string, variables, select, plsql

this might be a simple one.  Basically in PL/SQL in Oracle I am selecting from another database:

```
select * From Store@dbstore.p009061;
```

What I want is that the value 061 will be coming from a variable name (myStore).

so it will be like this:

```
select * from STORE@DBSTORE.P||myStore||'081';
```

remember myStore above will hold  the value 061.

But the above doesn't work?  Can someone help?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, you can't do this directly in a query, you must use dynamic sql.

something like

```
declare
myStore varchar2(10):='061';
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM STORE@DBSTORE.P'||myStore||'081';
end;
```

Comment: Great I think that should work, thanks!  Also if I want to add a where clause can it be something like this:  declare
myStore varchar2(10):='061';
sStoreCode varchar2(10):='061';
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM STORE@DBSTORE.P'||myStore||'081 where storecode=sStoreCode';

end;

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe it should be like this?

```
declare
    myStore varchar2(10):='061';
    sStoreCode varchar2(10):='061';
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM STORE@BNSTORE.P'||myStore
                                            ||'081 where storecode='||sStoreCode;

end;
```